# Is :$I(t)= \int_{0}^{t} ( \sin x+\cos x)^{\operatorname{erf}(x)}dx$ complex or real for $t \to \infty $?

Tags: trigonometry, convergence-divergence, error-function

let us to check the behavior of this integral :$I(t)= \int_{0}^{t} ( \sin x+\cos x)^{\operatorname{erf}(x)}dx$, Really this integral gives to me for small $t$ values    close to $t$ as [shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(+(+sinx%2Bcosx+))%5Eerf(x))+dx+,+x%3D+0+to+0.5) , and it's values takes negative values and positive with imaginary part  close to $0$ , Really I want to ask this question: What is the value of this integral for $t \to 
\infty $ is it complex values or real ?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be real all the functions are reals

Comment: @ Youem , ok try x in (pi/2, pi), you will get this :https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(+(+sinx%2B+cosx+))%5Eerf(x))+dx,+x%3Dpi%2F2+to+pi

Comment: A negative real to a positive real power is complex.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos(x)+\sin(x)$
is negative in
part of the region
of integration,
and raising a negative number
to a positive real number
is not well defined.

More specifically,
if $a > 0$,
then
$(-a)^x
=a^x(-1)^x
=a^xe^{\pi i x}
=a^x(\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x))
$
and this is where
the complex numbers come in.